# How to use Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion here?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, inclusion-exclusion

A while ago I posted a question: [Coloring a Grid.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381366/ways-of-coloring-the-7-times1-grid-with-three-colors)

Online, I seem to have stumbled upon a usage of PIE [AOPS Wiki Solution AIME II #9.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_9)

> (1) Now, I have experience with PIE, but I do not see how to divide sets in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question to be how the principle of inclusion-exclusion is being used to determine the number of admissible colourings for a given number $n$ of pieces on the Art of Problem Solving page that you linked to.

The number of all possible colourings is $3^n$. From these, we need to subtract the ones that use only $2$ colours. We have $3$ choices of a colour to leave out, and then $2^n$ choices of colours for the pieces. But now we've subtracted the colourings that use only one colour twice instead of just once, so we need to add them back in once, and there are $3$ of them.

So that makes $3^n-3\cdot2^n+3$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you subtract $3 \cdot 2^n$,  what does it mean when you say: "we've subtracted the coloring that use only one color twice instead of just once?"

Comment: @Arnad27: A colouring that uses only red is a colouring that uses only red and green and is also a colouring that uses only red and blue. It was included in both of those counts that we subtracted, so we subtracted it twice.

Comment: the intuitive explanation is nice. Lets take the $n=3$ case for simplicity. So you have $3$ segments. The total ways of filling is: $3^3$. Then you have for two colors, $RB, RG, GB = \{3\}$. For each set ($RB, RG, GB$) there are $2^3 = 8$ possible arrangements. So you take this out (since two colors isn't possible). Thus far: $3^3 - 3(2^3)$. Now here is the issue. Why wouldn't you **subtract** $3$? It is possible to get (with only one color) $RRRRRRR, BBBBBBB, GGGGGGG$ which is invalid?

Comment: @Amad27: Exactly. We need to subtract that. Once. But we've already subtracted it twice. $-2+1=-1$. So in order to subtract it once, we need to add it once.

Comment: Ah - I believe I see this idea. So take just $R$. You added it once in $3^3$ then you subtracted it twice $(RB, RG)$, net $-2 + 1 = -1$ and then you added it once so you get net $-1 + 1 = 0$. Very interesting indeed, thank you for showing me this guide. Its better than using the formula, very interesting indeed. Is it is a similar idea for $4$ sets?

Comment: @Amad27: Yes, the idea is quite general. This is basically what inclusion-exclusion is. You count something, you find that you overcounted, you subtract the overcount, you find that some cases were included in several of the overcounts, you correct for that, you find that now there are cases that were included in too many of the corrections, so you correct the corrections, and so on. There's a lot of machinery to help you keep track of all this without having to go through every detail every time (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)).

Comment: I tried this in a different problem, and it doesnt work out well. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382185/how-many-divisors-of-the-combination-of-numbers

Comment: @Amad27: There are two answers to that question now. Also it looks like you figured it out yourself? By the way, when you find the answer to your own question, you can write it up as an answer and accept it -- that has the combined advantage of adding knowledge to the site and allowing you to mark the question as answered.